# None of [Index[] are in the [columns] - Modfiy multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, merge, glob

I want to modify multiple csv files with the following code:

```
files = glob.glob(r'path')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path')

for fp in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(fp, names=["vermittler", "vermittler 2", "vermittler 3", "kunde", "nachname", "vorname", "strasse", "plz", "ort", "geburtsdatum", "beruf", "land", "per_du", "login", "login 2", "nationalitaet", "rechtsform", "id", "versicherungsscheinnummer", "sparte", "gesellschaft", "zahlweise", "beginn", "ablauf", "beitrag_netto", "status", "risiko", "antragsdatum", "stornodatum"], sep=',',on_bad_lines='skip')

    df.to_csv
for fp in files:
    

    df = df.fillna(0)
    df2 = df2.fillna(0)
    #df1['sparte']=df1['sparte'].astype(int)
    #df2['sparte']=df2['sparte'].astype(int)

    df['gesellschaft']=df['gesellschaft'].astype(object)
    #df2['gesellschaft']=df2['gesellschaft'].astype(object)


    df3 = pd.merge(df,df2[['status','stati']].astype(object),on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])
    df3.rename({'stati':'status'}, axis=1, inplace=True)


    df4 = df3.merge(df2[['sparte','sparten']].astype(object),on='sparte', how='left').drop(columns = ['sparte'])
    df4.rename({'sparten':'sparte'}, axis=1, inplace=True)


    df5 = df4.merge(df2[['gesellschaft','gesellschaften']].astype(object), left_on='gesellschaft',
    right_on = df2['gesellschaft'].astype(object), how='left')
    
    df5.to_csv
```

But i get the error message:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['status', 'stati'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I dont understand why, because i've tried a very similar code but for one file:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'path')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path')

df1 = df1.fillna(0)
df2 = df2.fillna(0)

df1['gesellschaft']=df1['gesellschaft'].astype(object)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['status','stati']].astype(object),on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])
df3.rename({'stati':'status'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Does the error show up because of the for loop or becuase of the glob.glob.

I'm stucked :? maybe someone has an idea what is causing the problem.

Comment: Your code makes little sense since you're overwriting `df` in the first loop. You only end up manipulating one file... and I doubt `df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path')` works either.

Comment: The error shows up because your columns aren't what you think they are. You can use e.g. `print(df.columns)` (or better yet, a debugger) to see what's going on

Comment: But how can i apply the second code for all my csv files instead of one?

Comment: Using print(df.columns) gives me the columns back, but it does not helps me with my problem, print (df) gives me back [33224 rows x 29 columns], so everything fine... I dont understand the problem.

Comment: Well, maybe print `df2.columns` then. That's the df you're indexing on the suspect line.

Comment: Neither, your approach is not helping me solving this. I know its a beginner code, but you are not making it better. Anyway, thanks.