# Modify multiple columns - None of [Index] are in the [columns]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

Hello stackoverflow community,

i've build following code to merge a column from two csv files and it works perfectly for one file

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'path')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path')

df2 = df2.fillna(0)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['status','stati']].astype(object),on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])
df3.rename({'stati':'status'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df3.to_csv
```

Samples

```
df1 status     df2   status   stati

0     A         0      A       aktiv
1     B         1      B       beantragt
2     C         2      C       storniert
3     D         3      D       DV
dtype: Object   dtype: Object
```

Now I need to apply the modifications to various files in a dir, but it does not work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
dir = r'path'
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path')
csv_files = [f for f in Path(dir).glob('*.csv')]


for csv in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv) 

    df2 = df2.fillna(0)

    df3 = pd.merge(df,df2[['status','stati']].astype(object),on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])
    df3.rename({'stati':'status'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df3.to_csv
```

I keeps showing me the error message, `None of [Index] are in the [columns]`, when it comes to merging `line 22, in <module> df3 = pd.merge(df,df2[['status','stati']].astype(object),on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])` . I've checked the headers, columns and dtypes, everything is should be fine, as the first code runs well. I don't know whats wrong and a little frustrated with this one. Maybe someone has some inspiration for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which line raises the exception? `df3.rename`?

Comment: `line 22, in <module> df3 = pd.merge(df,df2[['status','stati']].astype(object),on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])` when it comes to merging

Comment: You should provide samples of `df1` and `df2` to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Given those two dataframes you've given as example, what should be the merge result? If what you're trying to do is to turn a given "A"/"B"/"C"/"D" status to one of the German terms, then use `.map`, not `.merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since running your example code with those two dataframes yields me

```
      status
0      aktiv
1  beantragt
2  storniert
3         DV
```

I think you're trying to [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapping) status codes in one dataframe to status texts. If so, `merge` is not the correct tool; use `.replace`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "status": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
  "name": ["Pea Soup", "Booze", "Scaffold", "John"],
})
status_df = pd.DataFrame({
  "status": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  "stati": ["aktiv", "beantragt", "storniert", "DV"],
})

# Create a plain dict mapping from status_df for use with .replace()
status_mapping = dict(zip(status_df.status, status_df.stati))  
print(f"{status_mapping=}")

df1['status'].replace(status_mapping, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

The output is

```
      status      name
0      aktiv  Pea Soup
1  beantragt     Booze
2  storniert  Scaffold
3         DV      John
```

and if `df1` had other columns, those would be left alone.

EDIT: if you'd need a separate column with the mapped value,

```
df1['status_num'] = df1['status'].replace(status_mapping)
```

for

```
  status      name status_num
0      A  Pea Soup      aktiv
1      B     Booze  beantragt
2      C  Scaffold  storniert
3      D      John         DV
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my ignorance.  `      status
0      aktiv
1  beantragt
2  storniert
3         DV` should be the right output! The merge tool works, but applying the code to one file, applying the code with `files = glob.glob(r'path')` and for loop to modify various files does not work... That's what I don't understand. Using `.replace` tool doesn't ssem correct, since I only try to get the column 'stati'

Comment: It "doesn't work" because you're only printing the last file after the loop, but without better information, I do think `.merge` is _not_ what you want here. In your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72604298/none-of-index-are-in-the-columns-modfiy-multiple-csv-files) you had multiple columns with similaresque names, but no real information on what you wanted to do with those.

Comment: I've taken out the other columns to be less complicated, the method stays the same and if it works for one it should work for various. I've tried to apply your example, but how can I make it work, when I only have for df2 a dict, for df1 it is not doesn't make sense to me, since it has only one column with requiered data

Comment: Well, for one, the naming "df1" and "df2" doesn't help anyone make sense of what you're trying to do, nor the fact that your working code looks like you're loading the same df twice (since `"path"` is a constant string), and the non-working code looks like `"path"` is both a directory containing CSV files and wherever df2 is loaded from. Can you confirm if my `replace` solution does what you need for one file?

Comment: Hey AKX, sorry for late response, in the end it worked for me with the merge methode, I had to change the datatype of some columns, that was my problem. Sorry for bad explaining and description with examples. I'm just getting into this. Thank you for taking time to trying to help me.